# regex to match a recurring pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for java that will match the following string:

number,number,number (it could be this simple or it could have a variable number of numbers, but each number has to have a comma after it there will not be any white space though)

here was my attempt:

```
[[0-9],[0-9]]+
```

but it seems to match anything with a number in it

Answer (score 4):

You could try something along the lines of `([0-9]+,)*[0-9]+`

This will match:

- Only one number, e.g.: `7`
- Two numbers, e.g.: `7,52`
- Three numbers, e.g.: `7,52,999`
- etc.

This will not match:

- Things with spaces, e.g.: `7, 52`
- A list ending with a comma, e.g.: `7, 52,`
- Many other things out of the scope of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work

```
\d+,(\d+,)+
```

Note that as you want, that will only capture number followed by a comma

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are starting with a String. Why don't you just use `String.split(",")` ?

Comment: yeah my bad. My answer might still be useful, though, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

^ means the start of a string and $ means the end.  If you don't use those, you could match something in the middle (`b` matched "abc").

The `+` works on the element before it.  `b` is an element, `[0-9]` is an element, and so are groups (things wrapped in parenthesis).

So, the regex you want matches:

- The start of the string `^`
- a number `[0-9]`
- any amount of comas flowed by numbers `(,[0-9])+`
- the end of the string `$`

or, `^[0-9](,[0-9])+$`

Answer (score 0):

Try regex as `[\d,]*` string representation as `[\\d,]*` e.g. below:

```
   Pattern p4 = Pattern.compile("[\\d,]*");
   Matcher m4 = p4.matcher("12,1212,1212ad,v");
   System.out.println(m4.find()); //prints true
   System.out.println(m4.group());//prints 12,1212,1212
```

**If you want to match minimum one comma (,) and two numbers** e.g. `12,1212` then you may want to use regex as **`(\d+,)+\d+`** with string representation as `\\d+,)+\\d+`. This regex matches a a region with a number minimum one digit followed by one comma(,) followed by minimum one digit number.